# using URLClassLoader gets the same reference as the default ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I'm trying to test that a class can be loaded to the jvm more then once but using different ClassLoader
so my code tries to load a class (class name "Tzvika") twice 
first using the default ClassLoader
and in the second try using the URLClassLoader
the problem is that i get the same reference for the URLClassLoader and the default ClassLoader 
what i'm doing wrong?

here code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tzvika t1 = new Tzvika();
    System.out.println("t1 class loader: " + t1.getClass().getClassLoader());

    Tzvika t2 = null;
    try {
        URLClassLoader clsLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL("file:/C://data/workspace/ashrait/tests/SampleClassLoader/bin/com/tzvika/sample/")});
        // same problem when i do this
        //URLClassLoader clsLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new URL("file:/C://data/workspace/ashrait/tests/SampleClassLoader/bin/com/tzvika/sample/")});
        Class cls = clsLoader.loadClass("com.tzvika.sample.Tzvika");
        t2 = (Tzvika)cls.newInstance();
        System.out.println("t2 class loader: " + t2.getClass().getClassLoader());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

here my console output:

```
t1 class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1a52fdf
t2 class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1a52fdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `URLClassLoader` without a parent.

```
URLClassLoader clsLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL("file:/C://data/workspace/ashrait/tests/SampleClassLoader/bin/com/tzvika/sample/")}, null);
```

Note also that you should specify the path to the root of the classpath, ie.

```
URLClassLoader clsLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL("file:/C://data/workspace/ashrait/tests/SampleClassLoader/bin")});
```

To better clarify, the constructor of `URLClassLoader` states

> The URLs will be searched in the order specified for classes and
>   resources **after first searching in the specified parent class loader**.

So when you try to load a class from this `ClassLoader`, it will first check the parent `ClassLoader`, which is the bootstrap classloader, for the existence of that class. Since that parent class loader has already loaded a `com.tzvika.sample.Tzvika` class, it will return it.

Now, since the classes loaded by the parent class loader and your `clsLoader` are different, the instances of these classes therefore  belong to different classes. So although you have `com.tzvika.sample.Tzvika` from both `ClassLoader`s, they are very much different.

That's the whole point of different `ClassLoader`s.

Comment: Your answer work, but I noticed two additional issues that I would aprisiate your answer. 
1. Why setting null in the parent? as I understand only the bootstrap's parent ClassLoader is null ? 
2. Why am I getting ClassCastException while casting the object from cls.newInstance() to com.tzvika.sample.Tzvika

Comment: @TzvikaVelich Yeah, I should have answered that earlier. I've edited with more details. Let me know if there's still something unclear.